# How to separate a part of so library that has circular dependency?

Tags: c++, unix, dynamic-linking

I have library `biglib.so` and I need to split it to `core.so` and `extra.so`. The problem is that functions in `core.so` call functions in `extra.so` that call functions in `core.so` again (circular dependency).

I was able to split it using "hand" linking with `dlopen` and `dlsym` however it adds a lot of unnecessary complexity to the code because there is actually a lot of functions on the boundaries.

I would like to build both libraries using "automatic" dynamic linking (link when loading to memory). However, this does not work because of the circular dependency.

What would be the best way how to solve this situation? I was thinking that it might be possible with some kind of dummy library like this:

1. Compile `core.so` and link against `dummy.so` that exports symbols needed by `core.so`.
2. Compile `extra.so` and link against `core.so`.
3. Compile `core.so` again and link against `extra.so`.

Would this work? I can see a problem if addresses of exported functions in `core.so` change between step 1. and 3. - then `extra.so` is will crash.

Comment: Are you up for a bout of refactoring? I think you would need to create another DLL or at the least move classes across DLL boundaries.

Comment: dlopen()/dlsym() tandem is the only option if you work on separating something like plugin library, otherwise (then it is not a plugin issue but two directly linked to app libraries) the only smart way to solve this is to refactor library code removing circular dependency altogether by fixing or introducing interfaces and adding missing abstraction layers.

Comment: @AmokHuginnsson Unfortunately, there is no way how to avoid the circrular dependency - it has to be there "by design". I could theoretically separate third library that is common to both `core.so` and `extra.so` but I can not do that either. Given those restrictions, dlopen()/dlsym() seems like only plausible option even though both of the libraries are compiled at once.